Need overwriting ability in a TreeSet with custom comparator
I have a need to keep track of stock market ticker symbols with the highest percentage moves since a certain time instant.
For example, one moment it could be TSLA with 1% move, followed by AAPL with 0.9% move, and at another moment if TSLA's move% changes to 1.1%, I want the value to be updated for TSLA, not maintain a second entry for TSLA with 1.1 in addition to TSLA with 1.0% that existed before. In other words, I want the Java set to overwrite it.
  @AllArgsConstructor
  static class SymbolAndPercentMove implements Comparable<SymbolAndPercentMove> {
    public String symbol;
    public BigDecimal percentMove;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      return symbol.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
      if (!(other instanceof SymbolAndPercentMove)) {
        return false;
      }
      return symbol.equals(((SymbolAndPercentMove) other).symbol);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(@NotNull KucoinTraderService.SymbolAndPercentMove other) {
      if (this.equals(other)) {
        return 0;
      }
      return other.percentMove.compareTo(percentMove);
    }
  }
  private final SortedSet<SymbolAndPercentMove> symbolAndPercentMoves = Collections.synchronizedSortedSet(new TreeSet<>());

The problem is TreeSet::add will consider it a duplicate if compare to returns 0, and not overwrite it, so I do a remove followed by an add:
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Set<SymbolAndPercentMove> mySet = Collections.synchronizedSet(new TreeSet<SymbolAndPercentMove>());
    mySet.add(new SymbolAndPercentMove("TSLA", BigDecimal.valueOf(0.010830)));
    mySet.remove(new SymbolAndPercentMove("TSLA", BigDecimal.valueOf(0.021661)));
    mySet.add(new SymbolAndPercentMove("TSLA", BigDecimal.valueOf(0.021661)));
    mySet.remove(new SymbolAndPercentMove("TSLA", BigDecimal.valueOf(0.032130)));
    mySet.add(new SymbolAndPercentMove("TSLA", BigDecimal.valueOf(0.032130)));
    System.out.println("Size = " + mySet.size());
    System.out.println("Percent move=" + mySet.iterator().next().percentMove);
  }

The above test code works fine, with a single entry being present in the set at any time, with the latest added percent move.
However in my real application many a time (but not every time) the remove call does nothing and there end up being two entries for the same symbol with two different percent move values. The same thread is receiving updates for a particular symbol, and even if it weren't it shouldn't matter since I'm  using the synchronized set wrapper over TreeSet, so I can't imagine why there ends up more than one entry for the same symbol. I can't write debug statements inside the jdk code for TreeSet to figure out why the remove method doesn't remove. What could I be doing wrong in my code that causes this bizarre behavior?

I know with IntelliJ (and most likley other IDEs) you can most certainly set breakpoints in the TreeSet code and observe what it is doing.   Another point to consider:  do you really need a complicated data structure to hold this data?  Would you consider coding something simpler from scratch?

“TreeSet::add will consider it a duplicate” You lost me there. You’ve not explained your data model sufficiently. How are your objects not duplicates? Do you have multiple TSLA objects? If so, what makes them differ? And compareTo is not used for determining duplicates in a set. Your Question needs editing for clarity and simplicity.

Are you sure you want a Set? From you description, sound's like you need a Map.

@BasilBourque "And compareTo is not used for determining duplicates in a set" - It is in a TreeSet.

@Sören But I’m guessing WalkingCorpse wants sorting by the percent-move. Tha would mean sorting your map by the value rather than the key, wouldn’t it?

@Sören I didn’t know that. Thanks for the correction. To quote the Javadoc for others: “… the Set interface is defined in terms of the equals operation, but a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method …”.

@BasilBourque since your doubt is clarified, can you unmark my question as needing more clarification?

You want to redefine equality and order entirely.  Trying to make this non-complete ordering work is extremely difficult and indeed there is no need to that.
Right now you've defined ordering as 'if it has a higher percentMove, it comes later in the ordering. If 2 things have the same percentMove, they are equal in ordering'.
As you found out, having non-equal things nevertheless be equal in ordering is really complicated and makes TreeSet not do what you want.
The fix is simple: Stop doing that!
Define an ordering that is total: No 2 things have the same ordering (a.compareTo(b) is never '0' unless a and b are equal).
To be specific, you've violated a bunch of rules. Your order operation needs to be consistent; if your compareTo implementation says that a is  below b and b is below c, than a has to be below c. However, if I have an [AAPL=1.0] and an [AAPL=3.0], then they are .compareTo wise equal to each other, but, [AAPL=1.0] is below [TSLA=2.0] while [AAPL=3.0] is above it; that's not consistent, and thus, treeset goes nuts.
We fix both in one go by definining a total ordering:

We never even treat AAPL=1.0 and AAPL=3.0 as equal. There should be no need; you said it yourself: AAPL should never be in the set more than once, therefore, we shall ensure this never happens. Then, there is no need to decree that all AAPL are equal to each other regardless of percentscore, because that fundamentally clashes with 'I want to order on percentscore'.

We make the ordering total by decreeing that any 2 symbol objects that have equal percentScore are still not equal; they are then sorted alphabetically by symbol. So, AAPL=1.0 will always come before TSLA=1.0 because A is before T. Voila: Total ordering; no 2 things can now be declared equal to compareTo unless they are 100% identical - same symbol and same value.


So how do we do that?

Update compareTo to take symbol into account before returning 0.
Never change a symbol object's percentscore. In fact, we're going to make that final to ensure we can't mess this up. Then, to 'update' a symbol's percentScore, you first remove the old symbol from the set, then construct a new object with the right score, and add it back in. TreeSet cannot 're-order' it self because you changed something. It can only put things in the right place; once it has put a thing in the place it should go, that is where it stays, so if you change that object such that it is now in the wrong place, treeset can't magically fix that for you.

  @Value // all fields are now final, yay. and equals and hashCode for free.
  static class SymbolAndPercentMove implements Comparable<SymbolAndPercentMove> {
    public String symbol;
    @With public BigDecimal percentMove;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(@NotNull KucoinTraderService.SymbolAndPercentMove other) {
      if (this.equals(other)) {
        return 0;
      }
      int c = other.percentMove.compareTo(percentMove);
      if (c != 0) return c;
      // secondary ordering: on symbol.
      return symbol.compareTo(other.symbol);
    }
  }


// ..... elsewhere:

public SymbolAndPercentMove updatePercentMove(SymbolAndPercentMove s, BigDecimal newValue) {
  mySet.remove(s);
  s = s.withPercentMove(newValue);
  mySet.add(s);
  return s;
}


You still need to override equals to return symbol.equals(((SymbolAndPercentMove) other).symbol); because otherwise mySet.remove(s); is not going to remove the item based on the default reference equality based comparison, right?

Tell me why this doesn't work:
@Override
public int compareTo(@NotNull KucoinTraderService.SymbolAndPercentMove other) {
  if (symbol.equals(other.symbol)) {
    return 0;
  }
  return other.percentMove.compareTo(percentMove);
}

The 0 value based on the symbol alone is for the remove call to remove the entry without regarding the percent move value. But when I run with this I'm still finding that there are multiple entries for the same symbol in the set.

@WalkingCorpse that breaks the rules. Given 3 items: x = AAPL[1.0], y = MSFT[2.0], z = AAPL[3.0], x is the same ordering as z, but x is below y and y is below z, which isn't a consistent ordering and breaks explicit rules for comparators.

And, no, you don't also need to override equals, because TreeSet only uses the comparator. This is one of the reasons you really, really want a total ordering with no non-equal equivalence ('non-equal equivalence' is !a.equals(b) && a.compareTo(b) == 0. Some comparator-based ops, such as sorting a list, don't mind non-equal equivalence, but it doesn't work in treesets: Any 2 items such that a.compareTo(b) == 0 means only one of em can be in a treeset. .equals is not called at all, ever, by treeset.

Sorry for the delay, thanks for the explanation.

If you convert your note to an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.
